Strugling with delegating a subnet 192.168.0.0/27
Okay, this is driving me nuts.
I'm trying to re-delegate a /27 sub-net of 192.168.0.0/24.
I've got the 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone.
This zone, besides SOA, have one entry:
1  CNAME   0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
Then I have a 0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone.
This zone, besides SOA, have one entry:
1  PTR     tilt-1.example.com.
When I query host -a 192.168.0.1 mydns-1
This is what I get:
$ host -a 192.168.0.1 mydns-1
Trying "1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa"
Using domain server:
Name: mydns-1
Address: 192.168.1.40#53
Aliases: 

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27387
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.      IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN      CNAME   0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN   SOA     mydns-1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. 2024050310 28800 7200 604800 86400

Received 129 bytes from 192.168.1.40#53 in 2 ms

I would expect to see tilt-1.example.com. in there somewhere.
So, what am I missing?
Next step is to change the PTR record, to a NS pointing to another nameserver.
The actual delegation :)
Anyone?
Edit:
If I change the 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.zone entry to
1  CNAME  1.0/27
And the 0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone entry to
1  PTR    tilt-1.example.com.
I get the right answer.
Changing 1  PTR    tilt-1.example.com. to 1  NS    ns1.other.com.
to delegate DNS, setting up 0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. on ns1.other.com.
The result is:
$ host -a 192.168.0.2
Trying "2.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63694
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;2.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.      IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
2.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN      CNAME   2.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
2.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN NS      ns1.other.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.other.com.      7200    IN      A       192.168.0.5

So still no resolution :(

One convention is that, when you delegate the reverse DNS for a subnet smaller than a /24 like your 192.168.0.0/27 subnet, via RFC 2317  IN-ADDR.ARPA delegation,    you create those records in  a zone with name that reflects the subnet mask, 0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. in this case. (AFAIK there is no hard requirement for that though.)
You delegate that zone to the customers name servers from the 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone (by setting up the required NS records) AND you need to create a CNAME record for every reverse PTR records that is delegated to the customers name server.
So your 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone ends up looking like:
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  86400 IN SOA ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                                2961345817 ; serial
                                86400      ; refresh (1 day)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.      86400 IN NS ns1.example.com.
0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.      86400 IN NS ns2.example.com.

; Reverse DNS for 192.168.0.0/27 is delegated to Contoso
0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN NS ns1.contoso.com. 
0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN NS ns2.contoso.com.

1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    86400 IN      CNAME   1.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 
2.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    86400 IN      CNAME   2.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
3.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    86400 IN      CNAME   3.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
4.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    86400 IN      CNAME   4.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
5.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    86400 IN      CNAME   5.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
; ....
28.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   86400 IN      CNAME   28.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
29.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   86400 IN      CNAME   29.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
30.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   86400 IN      CNAME   30.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
; end of deletegation to Contoso
; 
31.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   86400 IN      PTR   host-31.example.com. 
32.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   86400 IN      PTR   www.fabrikam.com.
; ... etc. etc. 

On the customers name servers they then create their own authoritative zone for 0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. where they can then assign their desired reverse PTR records for their IP-addresses.
0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  86400 IN SOA ns1.contoso.com. hostmaster.contoso.com. (
                                2961345817 ; serial
                                86400      ; refresh (1 day)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                604800     ; expire (1 week)
                                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                                )

0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN NS ns1.contoso.com. 
@                            86400 IN NS ns2.contoso.com.

1.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR ns1.contoso.com.
2.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR ns2.contoso.com.
3.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR www.contoso.com.
4.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR mail.contoso.com.
5.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR vpn.contoso.com.
; etc. etc.
29.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR host-29.contoso.com.
30.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN PTR host-30.contoso.com.


I have tried this same setup. I'm taking advance of the $ORIGIN expansion, so I have entries like 1  CNAME  1.0/27 for the 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone, and 1  NS ns1.other.tld in the 0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zone. Query returns 2.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 86400 IN NS  ns1.other.tld but no hostname.

And when you query ns1.other.tld for that PTR record? For example with dig PTR 2.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. @ns1.other.tld ? Does that generate a response?

Yes, I get the corect answer:
;; ANSWER SECTION: 2.0/27.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. 7200 IN  PTR     tilt-2.other-tld.
